# How to generate fixed width column in table from .xslt to doc

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

We are using .xslt file to generate .doc file using c#. But when finally table gets generated in doc file and user try to enter data in one column then it start getting starched.

**student.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<College>
  <Student>
    <Name>Sandeep</Name>
    <Branch>MCA</Branch>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>Raviendra</Name>
    <Branch>B.Tech</Branch>
  </Student>
 </College>
```

**student.xslt**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="College">
      <h1>Student Detail</h1>
      <table border="1" bgcolor="Green" width="250">
        <xsl:for-each select="Student">
          <tr>
            <td width="20%"> <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> </td>
            <td width="80%"><xsl:value-of select="Branch"/> </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
            </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Normally in word document we have options to set a column fixed width but can we do it using .xslt file so in final generated output doc file we can have fixed width columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XSL - calculating table widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399045/xsl-calculating-table-widths)

Comment: I don't think so it will help. In my template i can't have fixed width else in document it might shrink if it has less content. I need 80% of width of table. but when user input more text it should not expend. it should go to next line.